# Complex form logic (nested attributes, blongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, nested-forms, belongs-to, fields-for

I have models:

**advert.rb**

```
belongs_to :car
belongs_to :user
```

**car.rb**

```
belongs_to :engine
belongs_to :door
belongs_to :bumper
```

**engine.rb**

```
belongs_to :brand
```

...and many more, as you understand

I need to make 1 form for creating advertisement that would include car section, where i can fill all data about car (engine model\brand, door model\brand). Don't ask my why it is so detailed).

So basically it means that i need to create advertisement -> car -> engine, door, bumper in one form. I triend to user `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in model, `@advert.build_car` in controller and `fields_for` in view, but it is not working (maybe my mistake). In view i get something like `advert[car][engine][model]` (not like with `has_many` association, where i get `advert[photos_attributes]` for example).

What is the best solution in my case to handle all in one form. And please, provide code example controller\view\model.

By the way, i already spent a day searching for the best possible way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use th standard Rails form with nestings:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Also check Simple Form:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models